# Writing out proof for $E[X|\mathcal{F}] = X$ for X being measurable w.r.p.t sigma algebra $\mathcal{F}$

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

I am trying to write out a proof for $E[X|\mathcal{F}] = X$ for X being measurable w.r.p.t non-trivial sigma algebra $\mathcal{F}$

I guess this might be a duplicated question. So if you know the link, please comment it

I know by uniqueness and measurability of X and  $E[X|\mathcal{F}]$, $E[X|\mathcal{F}] = X \ a.s.$

But I am trying to write it out like (1) to prove it but I am note sure how to continue.
So is (1) going to work and if so, how should I continue?
$$E[E[X|\mathcal{F}]1_f] = E[X1_f] \tag1$$

Secondly, most textbooks I read don't explicitly show the interpretation of $E[X1_f]$ so I am confused by what $E[X1_f]$ or $E[E[X|\mathcal{F}]1_f]$ actually means

Comment: why is "I know by uniqueness and measurability of..." not a proof?

Comment: @CalvinKhor, It's definitely a proof but I am trying to see are there other tricks that can show it quicker

Comment: the equality $E[X|\mathcal{F}] = X$ a.s. is true by definition of conditional expectation. There is nothing to be proved here.

Comment: @Masacroso really appreciate your reply. I am new to probability theory and I am from an engineering background. So I am still learning how to think in pure math. Upon staring on the definition for a while, I see why you refer it to just from the definition. Because X is the conditional expectation given  $\mathcal{F}$ by definition and $E[X|\mathcal{F}]$ is defined to be so. Hence equivalent a.s.   I really sorry, I am really slow in probability theory, not sure I am intelligent enough for it

Comment: @TJT its fine. Many (almost all) students get confused like you when starting to learn a subject